# Can't use Selenium with a proxy

Tags: python, selenium, tor

The script I am making should change my IP multiple times and visit a website using Tor Browser. I got the IP changes to work, but I get an error when using Selenium with a proxy. 
My code is:

```
import socket
import socks
import httplib    
from subprocess import check_call
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

def connectTor():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,"127.0.0.1",9150,True)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def newIdentity():        
    check_call(["killall","-HUP", "tor"])
    connectTor()

def showIP():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("my-ip.herokuapp.com")
    conn.request("GET","/")
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print (response.read())

def process():
    url = "https://www.google.bg"
    port = "8118" #The Privoxy (HTTP) port
    myProxy = "127.0.0.1:"+port
    proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': myProxy,
        'ftpProxy': myProxy,
        'sslProxy': myProxy,
        'noProxy': ''
    })

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
    browser.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

    browser.close()

def main():
    connectTor()    
    print("Connected to Tor")    
    showIP()    
    process()

    print("Hew Id is")
    newIdentity()
    showIP()
    process()

main()
```

The traceback that I receive is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/peter/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 53, in main
    process()
  File "/home/peter/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 43, in process
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 66, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 97, in _wait_until_connectable
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.profile.port):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 43, in is_connectable
    socket_.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 369, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 236, in __negotiatesocks5
    raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

---

After changing the code as suggested by Louis I receive an error in the browser that says:

> The proxy server is refusing connections. Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.

The output I get is :

```
Connected to Tor
78.108.63.46

Hew Id is
tor(991): Operation not permitted
62.212.89.116
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code, once you set the socks proxy, it is in effect **for everything that follows**. So when the Selenium client (your script) tries to talk to the Selenium server (your browser), it tries using the socks proxy. You need to narrow down your use of the proxy only where you need it, and that's when you check your IP. So change `connectTor` to this:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def connectTor():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9150, True)
    # Save the old value so that we can restore it later.
    old_socket = socket.socket
    # We are now using the proxy for all connections.
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    yield # Let the contents of the `with` block that will use this function execute.
    # We are no longer using the proxy.
    socket.socket = old_socket
```

And change your `main` to:

```
def main():
    with connectTor():
        print("Connected to Tor")
        showIP()
    process()

    print("Hew Id is")
    newIdentity()
    with connectTor():
        showIP()
    process()
```

With this code, the socks proxy setting is in effect **only** inside the `with connectTor()` blocks. The `contextmanager` decorator and how it works is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager). The changes I've mentioned above work (I've tested them) but I've never used the `socks` library. I'm quite certain that there is a nicer way to code `connectTor` as a context manager than what I did but at least now you've got an idea of what the problem is and how to fix it.

You also need to set your proxy address for Selenium with the `http://` prefix, so:

```
myProxy = "http://127.0.0.1:" + port
```